# Keep subviews as original dimensions in UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uistackview

Currently I'm trying to make 3 buttons in a horizontal group of 3 that have equal spacing

```
UIStackView * menuButtons = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 16)];
  menuButtons.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
  menuButtons.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentBottom;
  menuButtons.spacing = 6;
  menuButtons.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;

UIButton* btnOne = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
UIButton* btnTwo = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
UIButton* btnThree = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];

  [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnOne];
  [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnTwo];
  [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnThree];
```

ive noticed when I inspect the frame of the button views after adding them to my stackview programatically, they all show different sizes than originally set, when I expect them all to still be 16

ie: btnOne CGSize(17, 16), btnTwo CGSize(23.5, 23,5), btnThree CGSize(21.3, 21.3)

I don't understand why this happens, and I've tried all the distributions but I can't figure this out when I'm not setting the frames on these views anywhere else

Comment: As I understand it, `UIStackView` **really** needs auto-layout to, well, *layout* its arranged views. Since you are explicitly setting the frame of the stack view, and not letting auto-layout / constraints to its job, you end up with unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example - based on your code - using auto-layout constraints.

Note that you do NOT need to specify width and height constraints for your `UIStackView`, as it will expand as needed to fit the arranged subviews.

If you *do* set a width constraint, you'll end up with (likely) unexpected results, because you've ***also*** specified fixed-width spacing of `6`.

So, you would want either:

1. width constraint + UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing, or
2. no width constraint + default distribution + .spacing = 6

Hope this helps...

```
//
//  StackTestViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/24/17.
//

#import "StackTestViewController.h"

@interface StackTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation StackTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupMenuButtons];
}

- (void)setupMenuButtons {

    // instantiate a UIStackView
    UIStackView *menuButtons = [[UIStackView alloc] init];

    // horizontal
    menuButtons.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;

    // spacing between arranged views
    menuButtons.spacing = 6;

    // instantiate 3 buttons
    UIButton* btnOne = [UIButton new];
    UIButton* btnTwo = [UIButton new];
    UIButton* btnThree = [UIButton new];

    // give 'em background colors so we can see them
    btnOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    btnTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    btnThree.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // for each button,
    //  tell it not to use Autoresizing Mask
    //  set width and height constraints each to 16
    for (UIButton *b in @[btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree]) {
        [b setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [b.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:16.0].active = YES;
        [b.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:16.0].active = YES;
    }

    // add them to the Stack View
    [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnOne];
    [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnTwo];
    [menuButtons addArrangedSubview:btnThree];

    // add the Stack View to self view
    [self.view addSubview:menuButtons];

    // tell Stack View not to use Autoresizing Mask
    [menuButtons setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // set X and Y position for the Stack View (just using 80,80 for this example)
    [menuButtons.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:80.0].active = YES;
    [menuButtons.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:80.0].active = YES;

}

#end
```